# How to run a command once inside a FOR loop using SqlTransaction in SQL Server

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I'm inserting rows from a `DataGridview` to three database tables using `SqlTransaction` with FOR loop and I want to insert reference of transaction in one table only once.

How can I do that?

I tried to declare `bool flag = false;` variable then inside FOR loop I have used

```
if(flag == false)
{
   .......
   flag == true;
}
```

However it did not help, because `cmd3.ExecuteNon()` is not working in either case if I declare `SqlCommand cmd3;` before FOR and instantiate inside IF statement or if I declare and instantiate inside IF statement.

```
string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PRMSConnectionString"].ToString();

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);

SqlTransaction objTransaction;
SqlCommand cmd3;

bool flag = false;

for (int i = 0; i < dgv_Purchase.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
    con.Open();
    objTransaction = con.BeginTransaction();
    //**************************Command 1 Code*******************
    string query1 = "INSERT ......";
    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(query1, con, objTransaction);

    //***************************Command 2 Code*******************
    string query2 = "INSERT .....";
    SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(query2, con, objTransaction);

    //****************************Command 3 Code*******************
    if (flag == false)
    {
        string query3 = "INSERT. ......";
        cmd3 = new SqlCommand(query3, con, objTransaction);
        flag = true;
    }

    try
    {
        cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery();
        objTransaction.Commit();
        lblSF.Text = "Success!";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Exception " + ex);
        objTransaction.Rollback();
        lblSF.Text = "Failed!";
        return false;
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to create a log of the actions undertaken in one table?

Comment: This Datagridview work like a cart and the reference key i want to insert in only table is like Bill Number.This Table keep record of all Bills

Answer (score 0):

If I unnderstand correctly your question, you want `query3` only on the first cycle of the `for` loop, and only after both `query1` and `query2` have been executed.

If that's the case, just execute both `cmd1` and `cmd2` first, and then move the execution of `cmd3` inside the `if` where you declare it.

```
string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PRMSConnectionString"].ToString();
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);
SqlTransaction objTransaction;
bool flag = false;

for (int i = 0; i < dgv_Purchase.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
    con.Open();
    objTransaction = con.BeginTransaction();
    //**************************Command 1 Code*******************
    string query1 = "INSERT ......";
    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(query1, con, objTransaction);

    //***************************Command 2 Code*******************
    string query2 = "INSERT .....";
    SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(query2, con, objTransaction);
    //****************************Command 3 Code*******************
    try
    {
        cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
        if (flag==false)
        {
            string query3 = "INSERT. ......";
            SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand(query3, con, objTransaction);
            cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery();
            flag = true;
        }
        objTransaction.Commit();
        lblSF.Text = "Success!";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        MessageBox.Show("Exception " + ex);
        objTransaction.Rollback();
        lblSF.Text = "Failed!";
        return false;
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes read correctly i just wanted like this.so anything goes wrong anywhere whole process rollback.let me play with this code.i will come up with you later.